# Correcto orden del head

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, accordion, datetimepicker

Estoy utilizando modals, datetimepicker y selectpicker en un solo proyecto y logre hacer que funcionara todo junto de la siguiente manera

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Estado Financiero</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertifyjs/css/alertify.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="librerias/alertifyjs/css/themes/default.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/triibu.ico"><!--Mentemos el icono de tribu para la pestaña-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fonts.css"><!--llamamos los estilos para los iconos-->

<!-- LINKS PARA DATEPICKER BOOTSTRAP -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><!--TAMBIEN SE USA PARA EL SELECTPICKER DE BOOTSTRAP-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<!-- TERMINA LINKS PARA DATEPICKER BOOTSTRAP -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"><!--llamamos a los estilos css-->

  <script src="librerias/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="librerias/alertifyjs/alertify.js"></script>

<!--SCRIPTS Y LINK PARA SELECTPICER DE BOOTSTRAP-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<!--TERMINA SCRIPTS Y LINK PARA SELECTPICER DE BOOTSTRAP-->
<!--SCRIPTS PARA DATEPICKER DE BOOTSTRAP-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>   
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<!--TERMINA SCRIPTS PARA DATEPICKER DE BOOTSTRAP-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" >
  <br/><ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#Resumen" data-toggle="pill" >Resumen Financiero</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Ingresos" data-toggle="pill" >Ingesos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Egresos" data-toggle="pill" >Egresos</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

    <div id="Resumen" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div id="tablaResumen"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Ingresos" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div id="tablaIngresos"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Egresos" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div id="tablaEgresos"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    <!-- EMPIEZA Modal para registros nuevos  -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modaladdCuota" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form action=""  accept-charset="utf-8" name="form_add_cuota" id="form_add_cuota">
        <label>Inmueble(s):</label>
          <select name="inmueble_add" id="inmueble" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" multiple required>
          <?php 
          if (!empty($inmuebles)) { 
            foreach ($inmuebles as $inmueble) {
          ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $inmueble[1]; ?>"><?php echo $inmueble[2]; ?></option>
          <?php }} ?>
          </select>
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_inmueble" id="hidden_inmueble">

          <label>Fecha del Cargo/Cuota:</label>
          <input type="text" name="date_add" id="datepicker1" class="form-control" required data-value-missing="This field is required!" />
          <label>Fecha límite de pago:</label>
          <input type="text" name="limite_add" id="datepicker2" class="form-control" required> 

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="new_cuota"  data-backdrop="false" >Enviar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </form>  
      </div>           
    </div><!--CIERRA MODAL CONTENT FADE-->
  </div><!--CIERRA MODAL DIALOG FADE-->
</div><!--CIERRA DIV MODAL FADE-->
  <!-- TERMINA Modal para registros nuevos -->

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

/*FUNCIONES PARA CARGAR COMPONENTES*/
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tablaResumen').load('componentes/tablaResumen.php');/*FUNCION PARA CARGAR LA TABLA */
    $('#tablaIngresos').load('componentes/tablaIngresos.php');/*FUNCION PARA CARGAR LA TABLA */
    $('#tablaEgresos').load('componentes/tablaEgresos.php');/*FUNCION PARA CARGAR LA TABLA */

    $('#inmueble').change(function(){//funcion para guardar en hidden_inmueble todas las selecciones de inmueble picker
      $('#hidden_inmueble').val($('#inmueble').val());
    });

/*TERMINA FUNCIONES PARA CARGAR COMPONENTES*/

//FUNCION PARA CARGAR EL DATEPICKER
var $jQuery_1_11_3 = jQuery.noConflict();
$jQuery_1_11_3(document).ready(function() {

        $('#datepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD', /*formato fecha (eliminar si queremos tambien horas)*/
            //minDate: new Date(), /*fechas anteriores a "hoy" no se pueden seleccionar*/
      });

        $('#datepicker2').datetimepicker({
          format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });

        //SE DEFINE QUE NO SE PUEDEN PONER FECHAS ANTERIORES A LAS DEL DATEPICKER 1 EN EL DATEPICKER2
        $("#datepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });

        $('#datepicker3').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD', /*formato fecha (eliminar si queremos tambien horas)*/
            minDate: new Date(), /*fechas anteriores a "hoy" no se pueden seleccionar*/
      });
        $('#datepicker4').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD', /*formato fecha (eliminar si queremos tambien horas)*/
            //minDate: new Date(), /*fechas anteriores a "hoy" no se pueden seleccionar*/
      });

});

//FUNCION PARA CARGAR EL SELECTPICKER 
var $jQuery_3_1_0 = jQuery.noConflict();
$jQuery_3_1_0(document).ready(function() {
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
</script>
```

Si se dan cuenta en el header repito dos veces bootstrap.min.js, ya intente acomodar pero si muevo o quito cualquiera de los dos deja de funcionar el datetimepicker o el selectpicker. Y ahora que quiero agregar un Accordion como el que muestro a continuación, no funciona correctamente el collapse (si lo abre pero ya no lo cierra) y por lo que vi en foros se debe a la forma de llamar jquery. Entonces mi pregunta es como se debe acomodar el head para que me funcione correctamente el selectpicker, el datetimepicker y el Accordion?

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

El ejemplo de accordion lo obtuve de https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp, el datetimepicker lo obtuve de http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker y el selectpicker de https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: estas cargando 3 versiones de jquery diferentes y 3 bootstraps

Comment: Si, intente dejar una pero siempre que la quitaba una dejaba de funcionar el datepicker o selectpicker o los dos, entonces por eso en el javascript le puse la funcion de var $jQuery_1_11_3 = jQuery.noConflict(); que fue lo que encontre para utilizar diferentes jquery

Comment: según las paginas de los componentes ambos soportan bower, que es un manejador de paquetes y versiones. Tal vez te convenga probarlo para que resuelva los conflictos entre versiones. Para un solo proyecto pequeño es instalar un monton de cosas pero te ahorra tener que revisar que versión minima usa cada cosa y así limpiar el código y evitar esos conflictos de versiones

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré